# Running procedure PL/SQL Oracle with Job that call another Job

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, scheduler, jobs

I have difficulties about running procedure X in job Oracle. in procedure X it is also calling each job.

Here it is my code (RUNNING JOB):

```
DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
  ( job       => X 
   ,what      => 'begin
ss_run_all_jobs3;
end;'
   ,next_date => to_date('01/01/4000 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   ,interval  => 'SYSDATE+2.5/1440 '
   ,no_parse  => FALSE
  );
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.BROKEN
   (job    => X,
    broken => TRUE);
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

PROCEDURE SS_RUN_ALL_JOBS3;

```
/*other script ... */
BEGIN ss_print_all; END;
/*other script ... */
```

PROCEDURE ss_print_all

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SEAT.ss_print_all
IS
 l_jobno pls_integer;
BEGIN
    dbms_job.submit(l_jobno, 'begin ss_print_1; end;' ,sysdate);
    dbms_job.submit(l_jobno, 'begin ss_print_2; end;' ,sysdate);
     dbms_job.submit(l_jobno, 'begin ss_print_3; end;' ,sysdate);
     dbms_job.run(l_jobno);
END;
```

/

EACH PROCEDURE FOR EXAMPLE ss_print_1

```
  vname := 'RUNPRINT_SEATFRONT';--||vcounter;
--DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_job(vname);
dbms_scheduler.drop_job (vname);
dbms_scheduler.create_job( 
job_name => vname,
job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
job_action => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe',
job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
--comments => 'test job',
auto_drop => false,
number_of_arguments => 3,
enabled => FALSE);
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value( job_name => vname, argument_position => 1, argument_value => '/q'); 
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value( job_name => vname, argument_position => 2, argument_value => '/c'); 
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value( job_name => vname, argument_position => 3, argument_value => '"'||xxx.txt||'"'); 
dbms_scheduler.enable( vname);
```

If there is running in pl/sql editor (TOAD Editor) it is running well, but if running using job (first code) it will be cause an error

```
    13:12:05 Info: Job #442 could not be executed.  ORA-12011: execution of 1 jobs failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IJOB", line 651
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 284
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

is it because first job still processing?

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The alert log will give you more information on the cause of ORA-12011 .  You may need a DBA to help you with this bit, depending on how your organization runs things.

Some additional observations.

Since 10g DBMS_SCHEDULER replaces DBMS_JOB; DBMS_JOB is retained for backwards compatibility with existing applications, but anything new should use the Scheduler because it has more and better functionality.

You code mixes DBMS_JOB and DBMS_SCHEDULER, which is a bad idea.  Choose one (i.e. Scheduler) and stick to it.

Also your SUBMIT code has a next date of '01/01/4000 00:00:00' .  New Year's Day 4000 AD is a long way off, so [the job won't run for almost 2000 years](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#ARPLS66583), then every 150 seconds.  I admire your faith in the longevity of your application but perhaps you should try getting it to run in a more immediate time frame first.

Although as you immediately break the job, perhaps you don't care whether it runs.